# AngularJS пытается найти provider вместо factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть `factory`:

```
'use strict';

var coreModule = angular.module('core.vkApi', []);

coreModule.factory('VkFactory', ['$window', $window => angular.isDefined($window.VK) ? $window.VK : null]);
```

И `provider`:

```
'use strict';

var coreModule = angular.module('core.vkApi', []);

coreModule.provider('VkApi', function VkApiProvider() {

    var settings = {};

    this.setSettings = function(vkSettings) {
        settings = vkSettings;
    };

    this.$get = ['VkFactory', function(VkFactory) {
        ...
    }];
});
```

При попытке использования VkApiProvider, получаю вот это:

> Unknown provider: VkFactoryProvider <- VkFactory <- VkApi <- SocialNetworksManagerService <- VkApi

Вопрос - что за VkFactoryProvider? У меня нет такого provider'а, я ни где его не использую. Как заставить ангуляр использовать factory без попытки обращения к provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что тут *пересоздается* модуль

```
var coreModule = angular.module('core.vkApi', []);
```

И в новом модуле, естественно, нет фабрики.

В данном случае нужно *получать* модуль, для этого нужно убрать второй параметр, в котором передаются зависимости

```
var coreModule = angular.module('core.vkApi');
```

[Ссылка на соответствующий раздел справки](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval)

Comment: Спасибо еще раз за помощь, проблема была действительно в этом.